Tradingview - Plot higher timeframe trend line in lower time frame
Is it possible to plot trend line base on higher time frame in lower time frame?
For example:
Plot Week level trend line in Day level chart.
Trend line set from Week[2] high to Week1 high
And show on Day time frame.
-
Extend Question:
How do I only keep  Week[2] high to Week1 high lines(Blue cirle).
And skip other wrong connect line (Red cross in pic)


The problem with this is, you cannot really use the security() function because you want to draw your trendline from wick to wick. With security(), you cannot tell where the HTF wick was formed.
Therefore, you need to keep track of events yourself.
Something like below should get you going:
var float weekly_high_price = na
var int weekly_high_idx = na

is_new_week = timeframe.change("W")

if (is_new_week)
    weekly_high_price := high
    weekly_high_idx := bar_index
else
    if (high > weekly_high_price)
        weekly_high_price := high
        weekly_high_idx := bar_index

This is how you can figure out an HTF high on your lower timeframe.
Create two other variable sets for W[1] and W[2] and then draw your trendline with line.new().

As expected, it really can't be done.
Thanks a lot!

Umm, I guess you got it wrong. It CAN be done. You just need to rely on your own algortihm instead of using security() as I showed you in my example.

Yes, I mean can not use exist function like security().
I'll try this example, thanks!

Hi Vitruvius, your example is awsome!
But here is another problem, I added in the article.
Can you give me some advise? Thanks

Please ask a new question for that.

Sure! Please help with it, I still haven't figured out the solution yet.
